# How to compare names in an arraylist using java

Tags: java

My brain in kind of sore and I can't put a finger on why this wouldn't work.

I have two arraylist

```
private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> name2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I need to check if the value in 'name' contains the value in 'name2' and if it is, iterate, here is my current code for this:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> getForeignKey() {
        ArrayList<Integer> foreignKey = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
        int intForeignKey = 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < name2.size(); x++)
            //System.out.println(name.get(i) + " ---------------- " + name2.get(x));
            if (!name.get(i).contains(name2.get(x)))
                intForeignKey++;
            else
                break;
        foreignKey.add(intForeignKey);
    }

    return foreignKey;
}
```

When this is printed out it will work fine for a couple of values, then it starts skipping numbers, so the output would be:

`0
1
2
3
4
5
5
10`

when it's suppose to be

`0 1 3 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 8 9 10`

What am I doing wrong? If more clarification is needed, I will try my best.

EDIT:

Please note that the numbers above are just example number of what the output should look like.

name contains:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

name2 contains

```
a,b,c,c,d,e,e,f,g,g
```

name(index i) checks if it contains the name2(index x) value, if it contains the value do NOT increment the foreign key integer, if it does not contain the value then increment the foreign key integer.

Comment: Huh? What exactly do you need to check? You have two lists, how do you need to compare them? In your example, what's the input? You only show the output and the expected output.

Comment: So, if String from list 'name' exist in list 'name2', do nothing. If String from list 'name' doesn't exist in list 'name2', store its index in list 'foreignKey'. Did I understood your logic right?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find the names which are the same in both collections?

```
private final Set<String> names = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
private final Set<String> names2 = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

public Set<String> namesInBoth() {
    Set<String> ret = new LinkedHashSet<String>(names);
    ret.retainAll(names2);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this isn't working (what's in `name` and `name2`?). A much better way to do this, though, is to use a HashSet to store the unique names and then extract them into an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Possible error - you use **.contains** to compare Strings. You should use **.equals** or .equalsIgnoreCase instead.

EDIT:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> getForeignKey() {
    ArrayList<Integer> foreignKey = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < name2.size(); x++){
        if (name.get(i).equals(name2.get(x))){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found){
        foreignKey.add(i);
    }

}
return foreignKey;
```

}

Comment: I am in debate with using equalsignorecase over contains, there are certain reasons, but that has been taken into mind.

Comment: From description: "I need to check if the value in 'name' is the same as the value in 'name2' ..." Contains and equals do different things. For example: "123456".contains("123") will return **true**, while .equals will return **false**

Comment: I'll change it, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Just edited your code. It is possible that I skipped } or smth, but you should get the idea.